# Execute method with out parameters in immediate window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, immediate-window

Is there a way to execute methods with out parameters in Immediate window? For example, while debugging I want to check if a string variable value can be successfully parsed into datetime. To do that I want execute datetime.Tryparse in immediate window. Is there a way to execute it?

Comment: What happened when you tried executing the method?

Comment: @Servy Suppose if I want to check the string variable result, I have to execute datetime.tryparse(result,somevariable). To do this the variable "somevariable" has to be declared beforehand (which i dont want to do because I'm just debugging my code in immediate window). Otherwise I will get the error error CS0103: The name 'somevariable' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @shanmugaraja Yes, the variable needs to be declared.  You'll have to declare it.

Comment: @Servy Can that be understood that you cannot execute a method with out parameter in immediate window unless you have a variable for the out parameter already declared?

Comment: I do understand it.  What don't you understand about the fact that if you need a variable declared, that  you should declare it?

Answer (score 1):

Just execute it in the immediate window:

[image]

Comment: The two lines of code DateTime dateTime;bool result = DateTime.TryParse(input,out dateTime);

Comment: No, only the TryParse. look at the immediate window in the image

Comment: Based on the code you shown, the two lines of code DateTime dateTime;bool result = DateTime.TryParse(input,out dateTime); is not part of my code.I want to debug the string variable "input" from my immediate window by executing the DateTime.TryParse method.